# JQuery replace input by a select using replaceWith

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a few inputs with existing value. I would like to replace inputs by a select with the same options but retain the original value.

html:

```
<span id="span1">
  <input type="text" id="input1" value="1" >
</span>
<span id="span2">
  <input type="text" id="input2" value="2" >
</span>
<span id="span3">
  <input type="text" id="input3" value="3" >
</span>
```

This what I've tried for now:

```
var inputs = ['input1', 'input2', 'input3'];

$.each(inputs, function(key, inputname) { 

  $('#'+inputname)
    .replaceWith('<select id="'+inputname+'" name="'+inputname+'">' +
          '<option value="1">0</option>' +
          '<option value="1">1</option>' +
          '<option value="2">2</option>' +
          '<option value="3">3</option>' +
        '</select>'); 
    $('#'+inputname).val("2");
});
```

So it work to build the same custom select for each input and I can set a fixed value but I would like to retrieve the original value for each input.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You would have to get the `val()` of the input before you replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the value before you replace it.

```js
var inputs = ['input1', 'input2', 'input3'];

$.each(inputs, function(key, inputname) {
  var inp = $('#' + inputname)
  var val = inp.val()
  var sel = $('<select id="' + inputname + '" name="' + inputname + '">' +
    '<option value="0">0</option>' +
    '<option value="1">1</option>' +
    '<option value="2">2</option>' +
    '<option value="3">3</option>' +
    '</select>')
  sel.val(val);
  inp.replaceWith(sel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="span1">
  <input type="text" id="input1" value="1" >
</span>
<span id="span2">
  <input type="text" id="input2" value="2" >
</span>
<span id="span3">
  <input type="text" id="input3" value="3" >
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to grab the value off of the element before you do the replace.

As an alternative, I wrote a simplified version using the native implicit looping that `replaceWith` will do.  I also threw in an extra method to select the previous value in the new select, if that is desired.

```js
$('#input1, #input2, #input3').replaceWith(function(){
  const isSelected = (value) => {
    return value === this.value ? 'selected' : '';
  };
  
  return `
    <select id="${this.id}" name="${this.name}">
      <option value="1">0</option>
      <option value="1" ${isSelected('1')}>1</option>
      <option value="2" ${isSelected('2')}>2</option>
      <option value="3" ${isSelected('3')}>3</option>
    </select>
  `;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="span1">
  <input type="text" id="input1" value="1" >
</span>
<span id="span2">
  <input type="text" id="input2" value="2" >
</span>
<span id="span3">
  <input type="text" id="input3" value="3" >
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I gave only 3 inputs in my example but actually I could have more than 15. This why I put them in an array.